# Fetch Facebook Event using location

Tags: events, facebook-graph-api

I am able to fetch user event but i require to fetch event using location wise like event in usa , uk , india.

How can fetch event location or b/w date range in Facebook

Answer (score 0):

**Way #1**: Graph API using the event object From: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/

When you call the graph API using `https://graph.facebook.com/{EventId}?fields=location` you should get back a location if it was specified by the event admin.  You can then try to see if that location is in the area you're looking for.  If not, then move onto the next one.

**Way #2**: Graph API using the event fql table From: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event/

When you call the graph API using `https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT name, location FROM event WHERE eid={EventId}` you will also get back the event and location.  If you want to be tricky and get a listing of all events for an authenticated user, then you can do FQL such as `SELECT name, location FROM event WHERE eid IN (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid=me())`

Comment: Thanks you but my requirement is to fetch event location or type without eid={EventId}

Comment: I am trying this query >> SELECT eid, name, start_time, end_time 
        FROM event 
        WHERE  name='Photo' AND location ='USA'
        ORDER BY start_time

Comment: i was try extract open event so not require event ids. and not require Query just i tried about lol, m new in Facbook API

Comment: You say "I am able to fetch user event", but then you say you don't know the event id.  I'm so confused.  IF you have the event, then you HAVE an event id.  With that event ID, you get the location exactly by either of the two ways listed above in my answer.

Comment: Yes, you right i b4 i tried API to fetch event using my id and friends id's , After tht my requirement chnaged fetch event location wise so i used "https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=photo&type=event&limit=1000" but not able to add paging here any idea how we can add paging because it's return next url which not able to extract data 4m FB, One more thing can we send multiple event request at a time like "q=photo,birdwatching&type=event"

Comment: Since I've answered your original question, let's get this closed out.  Please start a new question for your pagination issue.  Those are two separate things.  On stackoverflow we like only one question per questions.